# How do I create an array using the order and value from one and the key of another?

Tags: php

I would like to use the first arrays order & value to rearrange the second array. For example, the first value in the new array would be the the 69th value from the second.

1)    Array ( [0] => 69 [1] => 47 [2] => 29 [3] => 74 [4] => 82 [5] => 44 [6] => 6 [7] => 23 [8] => 21 [9] => 4 [10] => 7 [11] => 17 [12] => 42 [13] => 95 [14] => 80 [15] => 24 [16] => 56 [17] => 67 [18] => 71 [19] => 2 [20] => 61 [21] => 5 [22] => 9 [23] => 89 [24] => 49 [25] => 83 [26] => 68 [27] => 8 [28] => 26 [29] => 92 [30] => 53 [31] => 13 [32] => 33 [33] => 37 [34] => 87 [35] => 57 [36] => 59 [37] => 70 [38] => 12 [39] => 63 [40] => 88 [41] => 84 [42] => 39 [43] => 41 [44] => 94 [45] => 86 [46] => 58 [47] => 31 [48] => 15 [49] => 22 [50] => 91 [51] => 72 [52] => 85 [53] => 66 [54] => 79 [55] => 18 [56] => 3 [57] => 75 [58] => 76 [59] => 62 [60] => 28 [61] => 30 [62] => 32 [63] => 78 [64] => 81 [65] => 73 [66] => 52 [67] => 11 [68] => 1 [69] => 93 [70] => 64 [71] => 43 [72] => 25 [73] => 36 [74] => 55 [75] => 51 [76] => 10 [77] => 60 [78] => 77 [79] => 38 [80] => 65 [81] => 19 [82] => 54 [83] => 27 [84] => 34 [85] => 20 [86] => 40 [87] => 50 [88] => 45 [89] => 35 [90] => 90 [91] => 48 [92] => 46 [93] => 14 [94] => 16 )

2) Array ( [0] => [1] => ! [2] => " [3] => # [4] => $ [5] => % [6] => & [7] => ' [8] => ( [9] => ) [10] => * [11] => + [12] => , [13] => - [14] => . [15] => / [16] => 0 [17] => 1 [18] => 2 [19] => 3 [20] => 4 [21] => 5 [22] => 6 [23] => 7 [24] => 8 [25] => 9 [26] => : [27] => ; [28] => < [29] => = [30] => > [31] => ? [32] => @ [33] => A [34] => B [35] => C [36] => D [37] => E [38] => F [39] => G [40] => H [41] => I [42] => J [43] => K [44] => L [45] => M [46] => N [47] => O [48] => P [49] => Q [50] => R [51] => S [52] => T [53] => U [54] => V [55] => W [56] => X [57] => Y [58] => Z [59] => [ [60] => \ [61] => ] [62] => ^ [63] => _ [64] => ` [65] => a [66] => b [67] => c [68] => d [69] => e [70] => f [71] => g [72] => h [73] => i [74] => j [75] => k [76] => l [77] => m [78] => n [79] => o [80] => p [81] => q [82] => r [83] => s [84] => t [85] => u [86] => v [87] => w [88] => x [89] => y [90] => z [91] => { [92] => | [93] => } [94] => ~ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple I think this is what you want

```
for($i=0; $i<count($array1); $i++) {
    $newArray[$i] = $array2[$array1[$i]];
}
```

Comment: for what ever reason when I pass the array through the loop it drops the space

Comment: Is space at index 0 of second array? It's hard to say without more information but you have nothing in the first array that maps to 0

Comment: it was not an issue w/ your code.. whats odd is after your code when I used `array_flip` it would remove 0. 0 is a space. Ive fixed the issue. Do you have a way I can contact you, so I can bounce ideas around?